# A strange marker in safari for openlayers

Tags: openlayers

Using OpenLayers 4 displaying a map. I add a marker in the map and it works fine in Chrome and IE, but when I tested in safari, there is a black area in the location.

[image]

I also tried this sample https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html?q=marker in safari and it works fine.
Does anyone can help to tell what is black area? It is in the canvas and I cannot inspect it. My code in the same with sample, but the map is embed into our product, maybe there are some conflict of css, but I do not think it is the reason of black area.

Comment: You said that sample works find with your safari. but your code doesn't? I tried with `ol.source.OSM()` but it works fine. should check your code again.

Comment: Show your code and try to follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)